# Datatables - Nested array

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatables

I am trying to access the 'emergencies' array here:

```
{"organizationUuid":1,"emergencyUuids":null,"emergencies":[{"emergencyUuid":1,"emergencyTitle":"Student Fainted in Class","pickupLocation":"1122 Fowler St. 30309","possiblePatientUuids":[1,2],"identifiedPatientUuid":null,"emergencyState":"PENDING"},{"emergencyUuid":2,"emergencyTitle":"Car Accident on I85","pickupLocation":"I85 between exits 89 and 91","possiblePatientUuids":[3,4],"identifiedPatientUuid":null,"emergencyState":"PENDING"},{"emergencyUuid":3,"emergencyTitle":"Man had Heart Attack in Restaurant","pickupLocation":"Subway on Georgia Tech Campus","possiblePatientUuids":[5,6],"identifiedPatientUuid":null,"emergencyState":"ACTIVE"},{"emergencyUuid":4,"emergencyTitle":"Dog bit Man in Neighborhood","pickupLocation":"2022 Happy Hills 30456","possiblePatientUuids":[7,8],"identifiedPatientUuid":null,"emergencyState":"CLOSED"},{"emergencyUuid":5,"emergencyTitle":"Alcohol Poisoning at PIKE Fraternity","pickupLocation":"3212 Notso Happy Hills 30213","possiblePatientUuids":[9,10],"identifiedPatientUuid":null,"emergencyState":"CLOSED"}]}
```

With the following AJAX:

```
var table = $('#emergenciesTable').DataTable({
    "sAjaxSource": "/api/organization/"+token+"?verbose=true",
    "sAjaxDataProp": "",
    "order": [[ 0, "asc" ]],
    "aoColumns": [
        { "mData": "emergencies.emergencyTitle" },
        { "mData": "emergencies.pickupLocation" },
        { "mData": "emergencies.emergencyState" }
    ]
})
```

Yet nothing renders. I see no errors in the console.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set [`sAjaxDataProp`](http://legacy.datatables.net/ref#sAjaxDataProp) to point on the `emergencies` array instead :

```
var table = $('#emergenciesTable').DataTable({
    "sAjaxSource": "/api/organization/"+token+"?verbose=true",
    "sAjaxDataProp": "emergencies",
    "order": [[ 0, "asc" ]],
    "aoColumns": [
        { "mData": "emergencyTitle" },
        { "mData": "pickupLocation" },
        { "mData": "emergencyState" }
    ]
})
```

Then it works -> **http://jsfiddle.net/Lbx49x99/**

I dont know what version you are using, but some day the deprecated `sAjaxSource` concept is sunsetted. Since 1.10.x the syntax is

```
ajax: {
  url: "/api/organization/"+token+"?verbose=true",
  dataSrc: 'emergencies'
}
```